# Mostrar una List de objetos de manera inversa

Tags: java, lista, arraylist

Estimados programadores tengo la siguiente duda como puedo ordenar esta list de manera inversa e imprimirla x pantalla. Seria conveniente en vez de hacer String hacerlo de Tipo persona ? gracias

```
public class Datos {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Persona persona1 = new Persona("Ana ", "Fuentes");
    Persona persona2 = new Persona("Jair ", "Alvarez");
    Persona persona3 = new Persona("Magdalena ", "Jacobo");
    Persona persona4 = new Persona("Nayeli ", "Zaragoza");
    Persona persona5 = new Persona("Jose ", "Velazquez");

    List<String> Personas = new ArrayList<>();

    Personas.add(persona1.getNombre() + persona1.getApellido());
    Personas.add(persona2.getNombre() + persona2.getApellido());
    Personas.add(persona3.getNombre() + persona3.getApellido());
    Personas.add(persona4.getNombre() + persona4.getApellido());
    Personas.add(persona5.getNombre() + persona5.getApellido());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depende que vayas a hacerle a tus datos.

Para la creacion te recomiendo en caso de querer una lista modificable usar `Arrays.asList`

```
List<Persona> personas = Arrays.asList(new Persona("Ana ", "Fuentes"), new Persona("Jair ", "Alvarez"),new Persona("Magdalena ", "Jacobo"),new Persona("Nayeli ", "Zaragoza"),new Persona("Jose ", "Velazquez"));
```

Si deseas una lista inmutable, para por ejemplo solo imprimir los valores, te recomiendo usar `List.of`

```
List<Persona> personas = List.of(new Persona("Ana ", "Fuentes"), new Persona("Jair ", "Alvarez"),new Persona("Magdalena ", "Jacobo"),new Persona("Nayeli ", "Zaragoza"),new Persona("Jose ", "Velazquez"));
```

Si en su lugar deseas hacer una transformacion simple a los datos apra mostrarlos y no necesitas algun procesamiento complejo, te recomiendo usar el Stream API.

```
Stream.of(new Persona("Ana ", "Fuentes"), new Persona("Jair ", "Alvarez"),new Persona("Magdalena ", "Jacobo"),new Persona("Nayeli ", "Zaragoza"),new Persona("Jose ", "Velazquez"))// o cualquier origen de datos que tengas
.map(unaPersona -
> new StreamBuilder(unaPersona.getNombre()).append(" ").append(unaPersona.getApellido()).toString()) // mapeas de un tipo a otro, en este caso de persona a una cadena
.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder()) // ordenamos
.collect(Collectors.asList()); // aqui se lanza la ejecucion y se guarda todo en una lista
```

Alli como veras estoy usando un comparador para alterar el orden de los resultados (y un `StringBuilder` para mejorar el rendimiento).